# Three.js - setting cube color?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to create a simple 3d game with three.js. I am trying to create coloured cubes, but all the cubes just stay the same color.

When I create a cube I do:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, length);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color: hexColor});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

(which is inside a function)
Then I use the function twice, 
hexColor being 0x0000ff(blue) and 0xff0000(red).
The cubes do generate, but all the faces of the cubes are different colours.
I have also tried

```
cube.material.color.setHex();
```

But it gives out Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setHex' of undefined

Help please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()` doesn't have a color property. Try using `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: yourHexColor });` instead.

If you do that, your `cube.material.color.setHex(yourHexColor);` call should work just fine.

You can find all of the necessary information on the [Three.js docs page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshBasicMaterial) and, if you're interested, take a look at the dedicated [examples page](https://threejs.org/examples/).